# Reading clob data through jbdc and write to file trims data

Tags: java, arrays, spring, jdbc

I am trying to read clob data from an Oracle database and writing it to a file. The data is getting trimmed! I am unable to write complete data from database to file. Please suggest best way to write large clob data to a file?

Here is my block of code:

```
String fileNamefromDB = "graph.jrxml";
File data = new File(fileNamefromDB);
while (rs.next()) {
    Reader dataReader =  rs.getClob("xml_clob").getCharacterStream();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(data);
    char[] buffer = new char[1];
    while (dataReader.read(buffer) > 0) {
      writer.write(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `read()` instead if you are only using a buffer of 1 character? Also note that only `-1` signals end of stream; it shouldn't normally happen in correctly implemented streams, but it is not outside the realm of possibilities that you might occasionally read no bytes even though end of streams isn't reached.

Comment: Also, have you verified that the clob itself isn't actually trimmed?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your response the issue was I was not flushing the data out of memory....this solved my issue: